# Is there a date format to use when loading Firestore from json file

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I'm loading a json file into Firestore.  I have date fields formatted as:

```
{"createdon":"2019-01-03T20:53:41Z","modifiedon":"2019-02-03T20:53:41Z",
```

These are stored in Firestore as strings.

The load is done by :

```
    firestore.collection(collectionKey).doc('name1').collection('kitlist').add(data[docKey]).then((res) => {
    console.log("Document " + docKey + " successfully written!");
}).catch((error) => {
   console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
```

Is there a way to make the dates load as Firestore timestamps? Should I use a different json date format?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using the JS SDK, use the native JS Date to upload dates:

```
{createdon: new Date("2019-01-03T20:53:41Z"), modifiedon:new Date("2019-02-03T20:53:41Z")}
```